# Error infinite a value altair jupyter [-infinite,infinite]

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, jupyter, kibana, altair

Hi all I've a problem on creating a graph on altair. The graph works without problem the only drawback is that when I'm going to interact with it I obtain the followings labels.
Antoher thing that I want to solve is that I want that the system need to be react in bot cases so when I interact with the first dropdown and when I interact with the second or both. All this problems are solved in the sense that doesn't appear if and only if I substitute " transform_filter((selection & selection1))" with " transform_filter((selection | selection1))" but in case I made this substitution and I want to make a filtering of elements according to both filters it doesn't work.

> ```
> Infinite extent for field "timestamp": [Infinity, -Infinity] 
> Infinite extent for field "Y1": [Infinity, -Infinity]
> ```

```
input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=[[1,2,3,4,5],[4],[3],[1],[2],[5],[1,4,5],[3,4,5],[1,2,3,4],[1,3,5],[1,3,4],[1,2,5],[1,2,4],[1,2,3],[4,5],[4,2],[2,3],[1,2],[5,3],[3,4],[2,5],[1,4],[1,5],[1,2],[1,3]])
selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['FIELD1'], bind=input_dropdown, name='FIELD1: ')

#dropdown
input_dropdown1 = alt.binding_select(options=[['M13','M14','M15','M16'],['M14'],['M13'],['M16'],['M15']])
selection1 = alt.selection_single(fields=['FIELD2'], bind=input_dropdown1, name='FIELD2: ')
#shape
selection_Operation= alt.selection_multi(fields=['FIELD1:N'],bind='legend')
shape_Operation = alt.condition(selection_Operation ,alt.Shape('FIELD1:N'), alt.value('lightgray'))

color = alt.condition(selection,alt.Color('FIELD2:N'), alt.value('lightgray'))

interaction1 = alt.selection_interval(bind='scales', on="[mousedown[event.altKey], mouseup] > mousemove", translate="[mousedown[event.altKey], mouseup] > mousemove!",
    zoom="wheel![event.altKey]"
)

interactionY = alt.selection_interval(bind='scales', encodings=['x'],on="[mousedown[event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove",translate="[mousedown[event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove!",
    zoom="wheel![event.shiftKey]")
Scatter=alt.Chart(pd_df_).mark_point(filled=True).encode(x=alt.X('timestamp:T', title='TIMESTAMP'),y=alt.Y('Y1:Q', title='Y1'),  color=color,shape=shape_Operation,tooltip = ['Y1:N','FIELD1:N','KIND:N','FIELD2:N', alt.Tooltip('timestamp:T', format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),'CODE:N']
).add_selection(interaction1,interactionY,selection,selection1,selection_Operation).transform_filter((selection & selection1))

ScatterLine

#saveVegaLiteVis(es, 'index-pattern', 'graph1', ScatterLine, timeField=True)
```

Comment: You can check if [any of these issues](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues?q=is%3Aissue+infinite+transform) have helpful solutions (especially [this comment](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/6963#issuecomment-710741996) seems relevant. If not, could you recreate this example with sample data or post a subset of your data so that we can try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: In the meanwhile I check something on the first link post a subset of my own data:


`TIMESTAMP              |Y1    |     FIELD1    |   FIELD2
2019-04-22 09:52:12|0.52 |            3      |    M13
2020-07-09 10:22:10|3      |             1     |      M14`


as you can see the values into Field1 could be 1,2,3,4,5 instead field2 could be M13,M14,M15,M16. @joelostblom